# Spatie Laravel user role permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am new to Laravel. I have implemented a search with user role and permission. If I selected a role it should display all the users assigned to that role...same way for permission and if I search for the particular user it should display the user details with role and permission.

User with particular role

```
User::role('admin')->get()
```

User with particular permission

```
User::permission('view')->get();
```

User with name

```
User::with('roles.permissions')->with('permissions')->where('name' , 'testadmin')->first();
```

I wanted to know is this correct? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the users who has **roles/Permission** by using `wherehas` method

To Get all the User with Admin Role

```
User::with('roles')
   ->whereHas('roles',function($query){
        return $query->whereIn('name',['Admin']);
   });
```

To get users who have view permission

```
User::with(['permission'])
    ->whereHas('permission',function($query){
        return $query->whereIn('name',['view']);
    });
```